# Which are the default partition flags for Packard Bell Easynote laptops?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, flag

How should the partition flags be set for the default partitions of Packard Bell laptops?

- PQSERVICE
- SYSTEM RESERVED
- WINDOWS (Seven)

In my case, the model is an EasyNote LJ65.

Which partition should have the boot flag on ?
Which one the diag flag ?
Any should have hidden flag ?

Can someone check a working configuration with gParted or equivalent?

Comment: I'm kinda curious what happened to the defaults, and how they might have gotten changed. Its PRETTY hard to muck those up accidentally.

Comment: Judging by no replies, upvotes or marks as answers, I'd say we will never find out.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek: I had to alter the defaults for the following reason. The drive which had bad sectors was cloned to a larger one, and the files where then extracted to one additional partition, which was appended at the end of the disk. I had to set the first three partitions as hidden, so that I could access the last partition from within Windows when the disk was in an external enclosure. Else, Windows could not access to the last partition and mount it. I had forgotten if the "diag" flag was for "PQservice" or for "System Reserved".

Answer (score 0):

Size is usually a give away as to what goes wheres, and name.

Windows - Boot

PQservice - hidden (It's how you restore to factory state)

System Reserved - diag (Unless you don't want your system to boot)

Comment: [Diag is used to indicate the partition is used for diagnostics / recovery.](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dhelp-manual)